# Does any simple way to show svg code in IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I want to create a line with svg in html and show in old browsers like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <polyline points="10,10 50,10 150,100 250,100 300,150" fill="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)"/>
    </svg>

  </body>
</html>
```

This code will show in new browsers normally but in IE6 it doesn't show anything. 
please help me how can i fix it to show my svg code in IE6

This page : https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html
said I must to download Adobe SVG Viewer 3.03 plugin to view svg in IE4-IE8, but i can't find plugin.

Please help me

Comment: Yeah, switch your SVG to `<embed>` and see what happens.  Many machines had plugins which supported this already.  Also, I think there's a way to convert SVG to VRML, which if I remember correctly was supported in old IE?

Comment: The download site at https://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg/adobe-svg-viewer-download-area.html still seems to work.